# Depth First Search With Recursion Through Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, depth-first-search

I'll cut to the chase and say that basically what I'm trying to do is find the longest path of a graph that is represented as a python dictionary. In the dictionary the keys are nodes, and then the values are the lists of nodes that the key has a path to. I've been trying to do this with DFS but I've never done it in python before and I think I'm misunderstanding how it should work. Some of the minor details of how python functions work are lost on me since I don't have much experience with it.

My function is here:

```
def lpath(data, node):
     paths = []

     def search(node, path):
          if len(data.get(node)) == 0:
               paths.append(path)
               return None
          if node not in path:
               path.append(node)
               for n in list(data.get(node)):
                    return search(n, path)

     search(node, [])

     longPath = max(paths, key=len)
     return longPath
```

The first if statement is meant to check if the node (key) has an empty value, and it should exit the current function on the stack if it does since it's and ending node. That condition is the one that seems to be causing me the most trouble as once it reaches a node with an empty value I get a maximum recursion depth error.

Comment: You `search` function always returns `None` (either directly or recursively), so why return anything at all?  The return value isn't even used.

Comment: Please provide a possible `node` which will serve as input as well as the expected output for that `node`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you didn't consider visited nodes. To solve this issue add a dictionary with keys of nodes and values of if the node is visited or not. when you add a node to the path, mark the node visited. doing so you won't encounter the problem you are having right now. something like this:

```
if node not in path:
    path.append(node)
    visited[node] = True
    for n in list(data.get(node)):
        if visited.get(n) is None or visited.get(n) == False :
            return search(n, path)
```